# Как сократить расстояние между картинкой и текстом?

Tags: html, css

Как сократить расстояние между картинкой и текстом ?

```css
.section_blog{
  background-color:#fffcfc;
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:80px;
  
}
.section_blog_image {
  margin:0 auto;
  margin-bottom:40px;
  
}

.section_blog_text{
  float:right;
  width:50%;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:left;
}
.section_blog_text>span{
  color:Silver;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<section class="section_blog">
    <h2>Blog</h2>
    <section class="section_blog_1">
      <section class="section_blog_image">
        <img  src="img/123.jpg" width="250" height="200">
        <section class="section_blog_text">
        <h2>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h2> <br>
        <span class="span_h">01.01.2017</span> <br>
        <span >Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. 
          It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making 
          it over 2000 years old.</span>
        </section>
      </section>
    </section>
    <section class="section_blog_1">
      <section class="section_blog_image">
        <img  src="img/456.jpg" width="250" height="200">
        <section class="section_blog_text">
        <h2>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h2> <br>
        <span class="span_h">31.12.2016</span> <br>
        <span >Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. 
          It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making 
          it over 2000 years old.</span>
      </section>
      </section>
    </section>
  </section>
```

Comment: при таком коде никак. нужно использовать flex.

Comment: А если задать ширину не 50%, а calc(100% - ширина картинки)